# Margining two arrays of different sizes and placing values next to each other

Tags: python, arrays

I'm trying to merge two arrays and place thier respective values next to each other. For example, have those two arrays.

```
Arry1 = [{"key" : "A", "values": [[111], [222]]}]
Arry2 = [333,444,555]
```

I'd like to marge them and have the output look like this.

```
output = [{"key" : "A", "values": [[111, 333], [222,444]]}]
```

I tried this method, however the output contains extra unacecery arrays within the main array.

```
out = []
for t in zip(Arry1[0]["values"],Arry2):
    for x in t:
        out.append(x)
#output [[111], [333], [222], [444]]
```

Comment: Please fix this question - the number of braces don't even match.

Comment: I put the 555 because my arrys aren't always the same size. For example, one will have two values, whereas the other may have more than two. If this is the case, I'd like to ignore the extra value and only match the first ones.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hate to add another answer when the previous two do the job, but I think that the neatest answer leverage's python's `zip` function:

```py
Arry1 = [{"key" : "A", "values": [[111], [222]]}]
Arry2 = [333,444,555]

for x, y in zip(Arry1[0]["values"], Arry2):
    x.append(y)
```

Answer (score 2):

Please fix your brackets,
Also does this work for you?
Considering I got the brackets right...

```
Arry1 = [{"key" : "A", "values": [[111], [222]]}]
Arry2 = [333,444,555]

for arr in Arry1[0].values():
    index = 0
    if type(arr) == list:
        for arr2 in arr:
            arr2.append(Arry2[index])
            index += 1
            
print(Arry1)
```

Output

```
[{'key': 'A', 'values': [[111, 333], [222, 444]]}]
```

Answer (score 2):

I can't quite work out what you want, but i think this solves it(?)

```
Arry1 = [{"key" : "A", "values": [[111], [222]]}]
Arry2 = [333,444,555]
for i in range(len(Arry1[0]["values"])):
    Arry1[0]["values"][i].append(Arry2[i])

print(Arry1)
```

This prints out "[{'key': 'A', 'values': [[111, 333], [222, 444]]}]"